# Bridge packets from WAN port to a specific MAC address (e.g., Set-Top-Box behind router)

Tags: networking, routing, bridge, iptv

My ISP feeds me with Internet and IPTV; however, the current setup is that there is a switch before my Wi-Fi router that I want to eliminate.

Here is a diagram of the current setup (as you can see it is quite messy):
[image: Old state diagram]

And here is what I want to achieve:
[image: Desired state diagram]

I have SSH access to the router's OS (Linux). I also tried some of the UI settings for IPTV:

[image: Router IPTV settings]
however, that didn't help.

The only thing that worked partially is bridging WAN to LAN1 in the router; however, after that, all devices connected to the switch did not have Internet.

**The limitation that I have is that the router and the STB (Set-Top-Box)
are in different rooms and I have only one Ethernet cable between the rooms.**

What I imagined was bridging the packets or the frames that come from the WAN to the STB's MAC or IP address.

I also checked with the ISP if they could provide me with VLAN IDs of the Internet and IPTV packets, but they couldn't provide me with that.

I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: (1) Please try harder to explain your situation *in words,* so people don't need to see the images.   (2) What is "STB"?   (3) Please upload your images to imgur.com.  You should be able to do that when you [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi, STB is Set-Top-Box, used for IPTV, apologies for not mentioning this. The imigues should be on imgur now.

Comment: Is the switch you want to get rid of provided by the ISP, or is it your own switch? Are the UI settings for IPTV "you tried" the ones that are actually working? Reason I'm asking: The ISP probably has a particular way to do IPTV, using VLANs or other things, and it may do that in the switch (if ISP provided) or the router (if ISP provided). To replace that with some other configuration, one first has to understand how the IPTV stuff is actually done.

Comment: IPTV is often delivered using 802.1Q (a different VLAN than the "_internet_")... your router might need to be able to deal with this.

Comment: Additionally, that switch between your router and "_the internet_" (modem?) will likely cause you all sorts of issues... it's a really bad idea, I'd disconnect it now.

Comment: dirkt I have an ISP provided switch that is 100 Mbps, but I have replaced it with a 1 Gbps - makes no difference (they are both non-configurable). I have tried all IPTV UI settings on the router and none of them work except for the port bridge (e.g. bridge the WAN port to a LAN port) - this way I have IPTV service, but all other devices connected to that LAN port do not have Internet service.

Attie I agree that a switch between the router and the Internet is a bad idea, thus I want to get rid of it, but that was the initial setup of the ISP ...